# Strange traffic on my dedicated Kimsufi Debian 8.4

Tags: networking, debian, dedicated-server, traffic

I own a [Kimsufi](https://www.kimsufi.com/fr/) dedicated server since more than one year, and recently I decided to completely re-install the OS. I installed Debian 8.4 Jessie.

I installed all the updates needed, changed my SSH default port, and disabled root login.
For now, I am simply running a MongoDB database on the server (changed the default 27017 mongo port), and a Node.js API, for development.
My personal computer should be the only machine knowing my dedicated server existence.

When logging to the administrator console of my server (Kimsufi/OVH), I can see that there is always some traffic, whereas I am not communicating with my server.

When looking at the packets downloaded, it's kind of weird, because every 30 minutes occurs a 4266 pps peak.

I tried to inspect all the data passing through the eth0 interface, using the `nload` command, and my server is communicating with some machines.

Is this "normal" ? If not, what can it be ?

Here are some screenshots of my control, panel... See that the traffic is pretty tough

**Traffic :**

[image]

**Downloaded Packets**

[image: Downloaded packets]

Answer (score 0):

A cause for the traffic could be the Kimsufi Manager Server Monitoring. I noticed that my server connected to some IP's I didn't recognize. When I looked at it closer, it turned out to be my server connecting to the Kimsufi Manager. This is how you're able to see CPU, RAM and SWAP usage from the manager website.

PS. If you wish, you can turn the server monitoring off in the manager.  See picture: [image: here]